# Linux custom NSS module, `_nss_SERVICE_getspnam_r` is called but `_nss_SERVICE_getpwnam_r` is not

Tags: passwd, nss, shadow

I'm creating a custom NSS module. I managed to make it work on my local Redhat 7.3 box, configured `nsswitch.conf` correctly

```
passwd: files SERVICE
shadow: files SERVICE
```

and confirmed that both `_nss_SERVICE_getpwnam_r` and  `_nss_SERVICE_getspnam_r` are called with:

```
getenv passwd username
getenv shadow username
```

But after I compiled and installed it on a different box, also RedHat 7.3, only `_nss_SERVICE_getspnam_r` gets successfully called. I print out logs to make sure that as long as glibc enters the function, there will be a trace, but still can't get `_nss_SERVICE_getpwnam_r` to work properly. There must be some other configuration that overrides `nssswitch.conf` isn't there? What could possibly be the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It was nscd getting in the way. It also caches the negative calls.